# Remove the Z Axis Column Line in Highcharts 3D

Tags: highcharts

I would like to remove the 3d line between the columns when using Highcharts 3D Column chart. Setting lineWidth and minorGridLineWidth in both X and Y axis does not seem to help.

[image: Highcharts 3d Image]

Comment: Something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/hbm6g08w/ ?

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much. I had missed the grindLineWidth attribute for X Axis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved setting gridLineWidth as zero [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbm6g08w/).

```
 xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,   
    },
```